# Good references for 'predictive models'?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, references

I am a recent graduate working as a Data Scientist and I often get lost in 'choosing' which model/models to use for a predictive task.

Just recently I was trying to build a prediction on time-series and the number of different models/methods available such as ARIMA, SARIMA, ARIMAX etc is pretty large. Not only that, but even though I can read more about them and have an 'educated guess' at which one to use; I still do not know the assumptions behind the models and whether they are suitable for a task at all. It is like a try and see if it works method.

So I am looking for some books/reference mostly concerned with traditional statistical inference models I can dive deep into and learn as much as I can about it. (I have a background in Mathematics and Statistics)

Thank you

Comment: You need to make it more precise, since in this form any book on machine learning and statistical models would fall into this category.

Comment: Traditional time-series statistical models (not ML). I think I am looking at discrete models as from my understanding the continuous models are stochastic analysis territory.

Comment: Than it was ambiguous, since non-time-series models also make predictions. Nonetheless, this seems to be answered in several places already, so check the linked threads.